# Why does one of these two key binds crash when they are virtually identical?

Tags: vim

This problem clearly far transcends my understanding of Vim. These two key binds only differ by two characters, otherwise they are completely identical.

```
" Move viewport up/down.
noremap <C-d> :exe "normal! " . (winheight(".") / 4) . "\<C-e>"<CR>
noremap <C-u> :exe "normal! " . (winheight(".") / 4) . "\<C-y>"<CR>
```

And yet, the bottom one (`<C-u>`) works as perfectly as intended, while the top one causes this error:

> E114: Missing quote: "\"
>   E15: Invalid expression: "normal! " . (winheight(".") / 4) . "\"

I have restarted Vim twice and made triply sure that only these commands are bound to their keys. I also tried switching them, in case that was relevant for some reason, but the `<C-d>` command still crashes.

So where's Waldo?

---

Output of `gvim.exe --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 16 2010 10:31:31)
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by george@reilly.org
Huge version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input 
+iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak 
+lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse 
+mouseshape +multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +ole 
-osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile 
+python/dyn -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title 
+toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim 
-xterm_save -xpm_w32 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE 
-DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG      -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOY/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  
/Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_MBYTE -DFEAT_GUI_W32 
-DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON  
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DMSWINPS -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjGOY/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib 
shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:AMD64 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   
winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:AMD64 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  user32.lib
```

I downloaded Vim from the link on the official Vim download page:

http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/downloads/list

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen when I include the `<C-d>` line .. what version of vim/OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`noremap` interprets `<C-e>` and `<C-y>` before `exe` does, so `exe` is then fed the control sequences, which are not necessarily interpreted properly. A possible workaround is to define commands and then map to them:

```
com! ShiftDown exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<C-e>"
com! ShiftUp exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<C-y>"
noremap <C-d> :ShiftDown<CR>
noremap <C-u> :ShiftUp<CR>
```

It's also possible to directly map the commands by using `<C-v>` `<C-e>` and `<C-v>` `<C-y>` to insert those characters:

```
noremap <C-d> :exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<C-v><C-e>"<CR>
noremap <C-u> :exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<C-v><C-y>"<CR>
```

Alternatively, `<LT>` can be used to insert a literal `<`:

```
noremap <C-d> :exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<Bslash><LT>C-e>"<CR>
noremap <C-u> :exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "<Bslash><LT>C-y>"<CR>
```

N.B. While a literal `\` may work, `:help map` suggests using `<Bslash>` to be safe.

Comment: You can also use `<LT>C-y>` in place of `<C-v><C-y>`. Also note that backslash is completely useless (though does not harm) in case you are using literal control sequences, like with `<C-v><C-y>` or plain `<C-e>`.

Comment: @ZyX Excellent, thank you; I've revised my answer to incorporate both of your points.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda: Very good answer. You have left me with no further questions :)